# Quais as vantagens de criar dll's no projeto e não colocar as classes diretamente no mesmo?

Tags: c#, dll, biblioteca

Na empresa onde trabalho utilizam muitas DLL's e eu tenho muita dificuldade em debugar e entender isso... Nos meus projetos(pessoais) eu sempre coloco as classes direto no mesmo e não faço como eles, acho muito mais fácil assim, qual a vantagem de utilizar DLL? lembrando que programo em ASP.NET C#.

EDIT: 
Eu tenho acesso ao código fonte da DLL, porém um dos problemas é, a chave da API que eu chamo está dentro da DLL, caso essa chave expire eu não recebo um erro especifico, eu não consigo debugar o método que tem dentro da DLL pois quando eu importo a DLL eu apenas consigo ler o verbo dos métodos e o nome dos atributos. Só consigo debugar se eu abrir o projeto da DLL e executa-lo lá dentro.

Comment: eu presumo que seja semelhante a criar uma lib para uso em diversos locais, a diferença é que elas são "compiladas", claro que uma DLL sem uma documentação de uso é bem complicado. No geral penso que é isso, poder usar a DLL para coisas variadas, agora se criar uma classe muito especifica que só faz sentido naquele software nem vejo motivo para mover para uma DLL.

Comment: Se você tem acesso ao fonte da DLL, você não terá problema em debugá-la... Mas como o colega falou, são bibliotecas que estão sendo disponibilizadas para você e é possível presumir que sua funcionalidade já foi testada e validada antes de sua distribuição, nesse caso você nem deveria se preocupar em debugar o seu código. Apenas faça a sua implementação de acordo com a documentação da API.

Comment: Galera da uma olhada na edição, não sei se consegui explicar direito o case, mas acho que responde o que vcs comentaram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei se existem mais motivos, mas aqui vão os que sei:

- Quando tem projetos de grandes dimensões o tempo de compilação começa a ser um problema, assim pode compilar as DLLs à medida que são alteradas, ou por exemplo, apos a comercialização do software, permite fazer updates de forma simples
- Permite carregar e libertar conforme são necessárias de forma a poupar os recursos da máquina.
- Organizar e distribuir os módulos do projeto de forma mais simples.
- Tornar o código reutilizável

Answer (score 3):

O motivo mais importante já foi falado: Reuso de código, você permite que outras pessoas utilizem o código que já está pronto o que (deveria) diminui o tempo para construir novos sistemas e (deveria) garante que o módulo é funcional porque você pode criar testes unitários de maneira mais isolada e ter uma cobertura de testes adequada.

Para complementar:

- Você pode evoluir parte do software de maneira isolada porque os outros módulos carregam a DLL, porém isso só acontece realmente se você não mudar a assinatura das funções declaradas.
- Você pode ter mais de uma versão do módulo em DLLs diferentes, o que pode ser bom ou ruim dependendo de como você carrega a DLL. Se você instalar suas DLLs na pasta do Windows (ou em algum outro lugar compartilhado pelas aplicações que as usam) poderá ter uma grave dor de cabeça (também conhecida como DLL hell).
- Você pode criar o seu software com uma arquitetura baseada em plugins (que serão desenvolvidos como DLLs) e com isso poder evoluir e incorporar novas funcionalidades até mesmo em tempo de execução (guardadas as devidas proporções de problemas com código que esteja executando, dependências de outras bibliotecas e versões diferentes de DLLs).